# delta import after updating data

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm working with Solr 4.4 and im not able to do a delta import using the url ,my

full import runs well. I have two tables resource and resource_data as given

below

### My Delta import Url

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/dataimport?command=delta-import&commit=true
```

### Resource

Fields:ref(PK),fields ..,last_modified(TIMESTAMP)

### Resource_data

Fields:resource(Resource table PK),value,last_modified(TIMESTAMP)

### data-config.xml

```
<document name="resource">   
  <entity name="resource" query="SELECT * FROM resource r where ref > 0  and '${dataimporter.request.clean}' != 'false'
      OR last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'" >    
    <field column="ref" name="ref"/>    

<entity name="MarketingActivity"  
          query="SELECT VALUE as MarketingActivity FROM `resource_data` WHERE  resource_type_field=81 AND  resource='${resource.ref}'  "
          deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM resource_data  WHERE resource_type_field=81 and resource = '${dataimporter.delta.ref}'"
          deltaQuery="SELECT resource FROM resource_data WHERE resource_type_field=81 and last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'" >
      <field column="MarketingActivity"  name="MarketingActivity"/> 
    </entity>  

 </entity>   
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use * in delta import? as you're updating data.Need more info.

Comment: Where should i use * ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM resource_data WHERE resource_type_field=81 and last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"